# MYSQL item transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MysQL, and I have a table called `abilities`, where each row is a unique ability that the player owns. Each row holds the data:

```
{
 uuid (unique id of owner of the ability),
 ability_uuid (unique id of ability itself),
 ability_id (type of ability)
}
```

The player trades the ability with another player, and I want it to update the owner `uuid` of the ability to the player they are trading with, all in 1 query. 
Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE abilities AS abilities1
INNER JOIN abilities AS abilities2 ON
  ( abilities1.uuid = 'player1_uuid' AND abilities2.uuid = 'player2_uuid' )
SET 
  abilities1.uuid = abilities2.uuid,
  abilities2.uuid = abilities1.uuid
;
```

This works, and will swap every ability that the player owns with the other player. The problem is that let's say the player loses ownership of one of the abilities, the trade will still process all of the other abilities except the one that was traded.

So, for example, if player1 trades `ability1` and `ability2` with player2 for their `ability3` and `ability4`, and it turns out that player1 no longer owns `ability1` for some reason, it will still trade `ability2` for `ability3` and `ability4`, so player2 gets screwed.

How can I fix this and make it so MySQL checks that they own the abilities that the server thinks they do?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, before and after, for what a successful trade looks like and what an unsuccessful trade looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the better way is to first pull the data from the database check if they have the abilities and then update. So this would make it 2 queries instead of 1. Edit: i really like Gordon Linoff's response aswell and will probably use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of abilities, you can count the matches and only have the `JOIN` succeed when all match:

```
UPDATE abilities a1 INNER JOIN
       abilities a2 ON
       ON a1.uuid = 'player1_uuid' AND a2.uuid = 'player2_uuid' INNER JOIN
       (SELECT a.uuid
        FROM abilities a
        WHERE a.ability_uuid IN ('ability1', 'ability2')
        GROUP BY a.uuid
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  -- all are there
       ) u1
       ON a1.uuid = u1.uuid JOIN
       (SELECT a.uuid
        FROM abilities a
        WHERE a.ability_uuid IN ('ability3', 'ability4')
        GROUP BY a.uuid
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  -- all are there
       ) u1
       ON a2.uuid = u2.uuid
    SET a1.uuid = a2.uuid,
        a2.uuid = a1.uuid;
```

Comment: would it pass the check if the number of abilities they owned stayed the same, but their abilities were different. so if they owned 4 abilities and traded 1 with someone else, this check would pass since they still own 4 correct?

Comment: @user3736638 . . . That is why there are lists with `IN`.  You put the abilities you want to test there.  Be sure that the "2" matches the number of abilities.

Comment: using this code, when it does match the where clause, it updates every ability that the players owns instead of the 2 specified, any idea how I can fix that, should I add an additional where clause at the end?

Comment: @user3736638 . . . Yes.  You should limit the updates to the abilities you care about (your original query did not do this).